# How can I round the edges of a shape made with the polygon lasso in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, shapes

I'm making a really odd-shaped sticker in photoshop and I would like the edges of the shape to be rounded but it's a weird shape. I made it with the polygon lasso and then just filled the selection with a color.

Is there a better way?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work because your shape is fairly easy, more complex shapes might require different means.

1. Start by going to your Brush. Make sure you're on a basic round brush with 100% hardness, 100% flow, 100% opacity.
2. Move the cursor to a corner and use the <kbd>[</kbd> and <kbd>]</kbd> to adjust the size of the brush to the radius you want. Of course this is with your Brush settings set to show the actual size of Brush (found in preferences)
3. Select your shape. If you put it on its own Layer you can hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and click on its thumbnail in the Layer Panel. If not you'll have to use other means to get it selected again.
4. With either Lasso <kbd>L</kbd> or Marquee <kbd>M</kbd> tool selected right click and choose Make Work Path. For a simple shape like this tolerance won't even make a difference.
5. Create a New Layer
6. Right click and choose Stroke Path using Brush and Simulate Pressure turned off

You can now group or flatten this with your other.

[image]

---

If you have a Vector Application such as Adobe Illustrator than shapes like this are often easier to create in there. For future reference. Or creating with the pen tool from the start in Photoshop.